# Force couchdb to reference attachments instead of duplicate in new revision

Tags: couchdb, attachment

I have a problem with attachments in couchdb.

Let's say I have a document with a big attachment (100 MB). It means that each time you're modifying the document (not the attachment, just one field of the document), it will duplicate the 100 MB attachment.

Is it possible to force couchdb to create references of attachments when they are not modified (couchdb can easily verify if the attachment has been modified with the MD5)?

Edit:
According to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-62) it should be able to do it but how? Mine (personal install) doesn't do it by default!

Comment: Not a great response, but I generally dislike the attachment feature and instead manage documents internally only referencing to them by URL. It allows you to also refer to the same 'attachment' from two entirely different documents.

Comment: Indeed, not a great answer :o) I read the following: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-62 so it should exist!

Comment: Which version of CouchDB are you using? And, can you reproduce this behaviour in a few number of simple steps? For example, when using Futon I create a sample document, upload an attachment and then modify the document after - it doesn't change the DB size between last two steps. I guess the behaviour depends on what API you use and how. Could you give an exmaple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, what you expect to find is the default behaviour of CouchDB. I think it could depend on how the API is used however. For example, following sample scenario works fine (on CouchDB **1.5**)

All commands are given in bash syntax, so you can reproduce easily (just make sure to use correct document `id` and `rev`ision numbers).

**Create 10M sample file** for upload

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=attach.dat bs=1024 count=10240`

**Create test DB**

`curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest`

Database expected `data_size` is about few bytes at this point. You can query it as follows, and look for `data_size` attribute.

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest`

which gives in my test:

`{"db_name":"attachtest","doc_count":1,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":2,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,`**`"disk_size":8287,"data_size":407`**`,"instance_start_time":"1413447977100793","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":2}`

**Create sample document**

`curl -X POST -d '{"hello": "world"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest`

This command gives an output with document `id` and `rev`ision, which are then should be used hereafter

Now, **attach sample file** to the document; command should use `id` and `rev`ision as logged in the output of the previous one:

`curl -X PUT --data-binary @attach.dat -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest/DOCUMENT-ID/attachment\?rev\=DOCUMENT-REVISION-1`

Last command output denotes that revision 2 have been created, so the document was updated indeed. One can check the database size now, which should be around 10000000 (10M). Again, looking for `data_size` in the following command's output:

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest`

Now, **geting the document back** from DB. It will be used then to update it. Important to have in it:

- the _rev in the document, to be able to update it
- attachment stub, to denote that attachment should not be deleted, but kept intact

`curl -o document.json -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest/DOCUMENT-ID`

**Update document content**, not changing the attachment itself (keeping the stub there). Here this will simply change one attribute value.

`sed -i 's/world/there/' document.json`

and update document in the DB

`curl -X PUT -d @document.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest/DOCUMENT-ID`

Last command output denotes that revision 3 have been created, so we now that the document is updated indeed.

Finally, now we can **verify the database size**! Expected data_size is still around 10000000 (10M), not 20M:

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/attachtest`

And this should work fine. For example, on my machine it gives:

`{"db_name":"attachtest","doc_count":1,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":8,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,`**`"disk_size":10535013,"data_size":10493008,`**`"instance_start_time":"1413447977100793","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":8}`

So, still 10M.

Comment: I'm using pouchdb so I don't have the same flexibility to manage the requests. However did you try to add another file of 10M to the same document? Will your db be 20M in size or 30M? I'm using couchdb 1.5

Comment: Ah, well pouchdb may be different - I didn't try it so can't tell. As of adding new documents with same attachement - to my knowledge CouchDB doesn't try to identify if the attachement is same or not - after all accoridng to the API you expliclty create new document / attachment. So what you can do is to manage this case on an applicative level. For example, store attachments in dedicated documents, or a dedicated DB, and "reference" them from other documents. In this case you may verify whether given attachment is already stored or not, before creating the new one.

Answer (score 0):

> It means that each time you're modifying the document (not the
>   attachment, just one field of the document), it will duplicate the 100
>   MB attachment.

In my testing I found the opposite - the same attachment is linked through multiple revisions of the same document with no loss of space.

Please can you retest to be certain of this behaviour?